# How do i stop my fixed position "overlay" div from scrolling to the top of the page once the button to open the div has been clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a form that can be loaded at any point from a fixed position header, now the actual form and overlay work, my issue is when i click the button to open said overlay if i am at the bottom of the page it drags the page back to the top. how do i stop it from doing this?

im still somewhat of a novice in the coding department however, i have tried a variation of positions to try and rectify the problem but had no luck. i dont know if theres some magical jquery that can solve the issue!

```
<div class="overlay1" id="overlay1">
    <div class="overlayin">
        <i class="fas fa-times" id="hideov1"></i>
        <h2>Request a Quote</h2>
        <p>Want a rough idea of cost for the design or product you need?<br> fill in the form below with as much detail as possible!</p>
        <hr>

        <form>
            <h5>Which service is most relevenent to your project needs?</h5>
            <p>Graphic Design</p>
            <p>Web Design</p>
            <p>I dont Know yet</p>
            <div class="radio1">
                <input type="radio" value="Graphic Design">
                <input type="radio" value="web Design">
                <input type="radio" value="idkyet">
            </div>
            <h5>Could you detail a description of your project?</h5>
            <textarea placeholder="Feel free to list things in bulletpoint form or paragraphs, dont forget the more information you proivde the better we will be able to understand your project!"></textarea>
            <div class="qbox">
                <h5>do you have an budget?*</h5>
                <input type="text" required placeholder="What's your estimated cost?">
                <h5>do you have an budget?*</h5>
                <input type="text" required placeholder="What's your estimated cost?">
                <h5>do you have an budget?*</h5>
                <input type="text" required placeholder="What's your estimated cost?">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
.overlay1 {
    width: 40vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 10001;
    display: none;
    overflow-y: scroll
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#showov1").click(function () {
        $('#overlay1').slideToggle();
    })
});
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: plz can you create a working snippet with you code

Comment: appreciate the response so thank you, however it seems that adding return false; to the click function seems to have solved the problem!